# Can't access admin after moving localhost to live server

Tags: database

Almost finished my site and thought I have completed the puzzle but there is one last frontier in my way and a rather annoying ankle-biter...

I moved my site off my localhost onto my live server everything was successful until I tried to login the first time and was denied access.. I requested a new password through the email I provided when i created the site on my localhost but the emails do not come to my inbox but when i try to recreate the process on my localhost I get the email and can change it etc. I have tried going into my DB>users>browse> and change my password and put MD5 so it becomes encrypted but still no success on the live site.

I have tried to search online for the answer but have been going in circles and would like to see if anyone can offer some advice I am novice level and eager to learn so if responding kindly use terms a novice would be familiar with, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Install drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/1791676)
2. Go to your `drupal-core/sites/mysite` folder in command line
3. type `sudo drush uli`
4. The console will print a link, use that to access your site as user 1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced this exact problem myself (and I'm also quite a novice), but I've been successful moving sites from development to production by following these steps. Perhaps you can try this:

1. Install the Backup and Migrate project in your localhost Drupal installation (https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) and do a manual backup of the database to a directory in your computer
2. Do a clean (empty) install in your live server. Follow directions from https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install  . Verify that you can log in!
3. In the remote server, install ALL modules that you are using in your localhost, and copy all your public files to your remote server installation. This means basically copying your local /sites/all/modules and /sites/all/themes (and /sites/all/libraries if in use) directories to your server. You also want to copy your /sites/default/files directory. But do not copy your settings.php file. Enable the Backup and Migrate module in your server installation.
4. In your server installation, navigate to /admin/config/system/backup_migrate/restore and manually "restore" a backup by choosing the backup file you created in step 1.

This should get you up and running. By the way, Backup and Migrate is a great module that will save you many headaches in cases of database loss etc.

There are more detailed directions here: http://www.seascapewebdesign.com/blog/how-transfer-your-website-one-server-another

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Hm, you didn't accidentally turn off browser cookies?

Happened to me a few times – no session means no access.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry, but turned off cookies provoke the exact behaviour in Drupal as described above, so I thought I'd rather put this up as an answer.

Comment: First I thought the same, but if cookies are misconfigured (turned off in browser or wrong domian in settings.php $cookie_domain) you simply get a page without being logged in without any error or access denied message. That's because Drupal logs you in, send the cooke and reload page. In the next page load you have no cookie (or misconfigured) so Drupal happily gives you a new anonymous page.

Comment: In my experience, the login process sends you to your `/user/username` page, but as the session is not carried over, you'd see the “access forbidden” message, if your permissions prevents seeing user profiles for anonymous users. Aside from that, the mail reset should work without browser cookies, too. So it's likely to be a different problem.